# Android Studio layout editor skill and setting

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

When positioning view using `android studio` layout `editor`(Design View)

1. Editor shows possible reference, is there a shortcut to skip or select through references?
2. Is there a `tools attribute` to set a view not to be a positioning reference?
3. Where are the settings specific to `layout editor`?

[centerVertical constrain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0bUo.jpg) 
[reference unwanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7i2Q.jpg)

Comment: try this video on youtube.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngH5Oj0_elo   and    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgA1WHnTLcM

Comment: My question is not about ConstraintLayout. It's about using Android Studio layout editor(Design View).

Comment: it is also design view...

Comment: I mean in the layout editor -> "Design" view not "Text" view, I'm ask about IDE skill not about any code.